# double click file， it can't display in current emacs windows

Tags: windows, emacs

I want to open a file, and let it show in current emacs frame.
I have tried lots of methods, but failed.
When I double-click the file. A new emacs frame shows and show the following warning.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried what it is suggesting? `M-x server-force-delete` and then `M-x server-start`? If double-clicking on a file invokes `emacsclient` that should fix it. If it is invoking `emacs`, then you should change it to invoke `emacsclient`.

Comment: "I have tried lots of methods, but failed." -- What were they? What did you try? Emacs doesn't start a server by default, so how are you starting the server, and how have you configured your system to invoke Emacs when you double-click a file?